# Eclipse plug-in regardless of perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, perspective

I'm currently working on a plug-in for eclipse. Right now it only works for the Java perspective but I want to know if there is the possibility to make it work regardless of what perspective I'm using.

For instance I'm trying to make it work for PyDev.

I want my plug-in to execute an action when I right click on a file from the package explorer.

If it is not possible I would appreciate any advice on how to change my plug-in so as to work on PyDev.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using for the context menu action?

Comment: I want it to display the file's info such as content or name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package explorer is not restricted to a particular perspective so that is not the problem. More likely PyDev is using a different view which just looks similar.

If you are using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to contribute to the context menu you can specify that the contribution is for any context menu and use the `<visibleWhen>` to control when it shown. For example:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
     <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.view.edit"
           mnemonic="%contributions.view.edit.mnemonic">
         <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
             <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                 <adapt
                       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                 </adapt>
            </iterate>
         </visibleWhen>
      </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

The location `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any` is a special id to specify any popup menu.

Comment: Thank you very much! 

This solved the visibility problem, now I am able to view my command on any Package Explorer but another problem arises.

When I want to perform the action, it only executes the command when I click on a java file but I want it to work on a python one too. Any idea on why this happens or how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A python file in what view? It may be that pydev uses a view which doesn't support the 'adapt' to 'IFile'. I don't use pydev so I can't say what it does. You may be able to see what pydev does by looking at the plugin.xml in the pydev plugin.

Comment: You can also use [Eclipse plugin spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#plug-in-spy-for-ui-parts) to look at selections in a view.

Comment: Python file in "PyDev Package Explorer" view. In this view when I have a Python Project and a Java one it only works for Java. For the Python I can see and click the action when I right click on a file but it does nothing so I assume PyDev supports the 'adapt' to 'IFile' .

Comment: If the menu item is appearing then the plugin.xml code is correct and there is something wrong with your action code. Do some debugging, add some logging, check the .log file for errors.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much for your help, you have been very kind and helpful!
I'll try!